# How can I collapse a div under another div on resize?

Tags: css

I have a left-column and a right-column.  When I resize the browser small, the right column spills on to the left.  I want the right column to just collapse under the left.  How can I do that?

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "left-column"> A bunch of content </div>
<div class = "right-column"> A bunch of more content </div>
</div>

.container { width: 100%; }
.left-column { width: 50%; }
.right-column { width: 50%; }
```

Comment: We're shooting blanks here, at least add the css and html markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any code it's hard to know.

I usually do this with `width:100%;` or `display:block` depending..

Comment: I guess this answer was posted when the question didn't have any code. How to apply this so that the two divs in the question are next to one another and the right one collapses under the left when the browser is resized? In cases without media queries, as this one, is this possible or is it only possible when px (pixels) are used instead of percentages?

Answer (score 2):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

  .right-column{
    float:none;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Use media-query for that and on max-width: 600px set ur resolution where do you want right column to fall into the new line ...